# R | Cannot find the cause of this error [Error: object 'EOT' not found]

Tags: r

My R installation seems to be corrupted and install/re-install hasn't yielded any solutions.

```
R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03) -- "Supposedly Educational"
Copyright (C) 2016 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

Error: object 'EOT' not found
[Workspace loaded from ~/.RData]
```

Any suggestions on where this error may be originating. I have already tried removing R completely and re-installing, upgrading packages etc.

System | Mac OS X Yosemite

Comment: Well, it looks like the problem is a result of **R** automatically loading your previous workspace (i.e. the ".RData" file located in your home directory). From the command line try entering `r --vanilla`--you should be able to use **R** as you normally would. Or, you could just delete that **.RData** file.

Comment: Thanks @SteveS. r --vanilla worked and so I traced it back to bad data in .Rprofile.

Answer (score 0):

You may have inadvertently saved an R session on quit.

Try:

```
rm(list=ls())
```

This will remove all environment variables.